# Joint density of discrete and continuous variables.

Tags: density-function

Let $X$ and $Z$ be discrete variables, and $Y$ is a continuous variable, I am interested in the joint density $g(x,y)$, and if the following equality holds considering any assumptions?

$\sum [P(x)g(y|\theta_x)]=\sum [P(z) g(y|\theta_z)]$

Comment: To avoid the question being closed, show what you did so far.